# Database Not Being Created In Code First Approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have seen a few questions like this, but none seem to answer my question - the most common response seems to be 'Lazy Loading - The database/tables will be created when you try to access them' in this case I am:

```
        Dim students As List(Of Student) = db.Students.ToList
```

The above is throwing an error, because students  table is empty/null.

Here is my (very simple) SchoolContext:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class SchoolContext
Inherits DbContext

Public Students As DbSet(Of Student)

End Class
```

Here is my SchoolInitialiser class:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class SchoolInitializer
Inherits DropCreateDatabaseAlways(Of SchoolContext)


Protected Overrides Sub Seed(context As SchoolContext)
    Dim students As List(Of Student) = New List(Of Student) From {
    New Student("Jessica", "Jones"),
    New Student("Chuck", "Norris"),
    New Student("Rambo", "John")
    }

    For Each student In students
        context.Students.Add(student)
    Next

    context.SaveChanges()

End Sub
End Class
```

And my connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=    (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\school.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20160205092922;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And finally my global.asax where I am calling the SetInitialize function

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Web.Optimization

Public Class MvcApplication
Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

Protected Sub Application_Start()
    Database.SetInitializer(New SchoolInitializer)
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
End Sub
End Class
```

No database seems to be created within my AppData folder and as far as I can tell, everything is set up okay? Any suggestions?

I am following the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAtVv1Q7ufM

Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned in my controller, I am getting the db context like this:

            Dim db As SchoolContext = New SchoolContext
            Dim students As List(Of Student) = db.Students.ToList

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this one out, in case anybody comes across a similar problem. I was using VB, so I imagine some things got lost in translation from c#.

There were actually a few issues for this. The first one was that the StudentContext class needed properties for the tables, not global variables:

```
'NOT Public Students As DbSet(Of Student)
Public Property Students() As DbSet(Of Student)
```

After this, the errors were easier to figure out. The second error was due to not having a key on my Student model, so I added this:

```
<Key()>
Public Property _StudentID As Integer
```

To both the property and the global variable. Next, it was not connecting to the database for some reason, so I had to download and install localDB.

Finally, it was complaining that I didn't have a parameterless constructor. So I had to add in an empty constructor in my student model.

FINALLY - everything is working (yay)